# REST Api documentation generation

Tags: rest, maven, jboss, resteasy

Is there any decent plugin which integrates with maven to generate REST API documentation for RestEasy ?

I have looked into [enunciate](https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/wiki) and [MireDot](http://www.miredot.com/)

*Enunciate* doesn't support java 8 and there is no timeline for it and *MireDot* requires license (basic features are free but regardless it has license and not sure if my company's policy would allow this).

So I was wondering if you guys can recommend me something else?

Comment: The latest Enunciate version does support java 8 at least regarding the API documentation generation.  See https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/releases/tag/v2.0.0-M.1

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links which you can look for. See if this is what you need...

1. [Ninja squad](http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2014/02/25/rest-api-doc-with-asciidoctor-and-gradle/)
2. [Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188425/spring-rest-api-documentation-using-swagger)